# How to scrape youtube information

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm using jsoup to **scrape** the information on the this youtubelink.I have face problem when **scraping** in youtube.I want to **scrape** the href. It like the picture [image]

I have try write the code to **scrape** but it doesn't print out everything. I can't figure out the correct  query in order to obtain the href. If someone can point me in the correct direction, that'd be great.Here is my code

```
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_biXHaJJOfs").get();
        Elements musicVideoLink = doc.getElementsByClass("style-scope ytd-watch-flexy");
        for (Element link : musicVideoLink.select("div.style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer")) {
            String Url = link.getElementsByClass("yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer").select("a[href]").attr("href");

            System.out.println(Url);
        }
        }catch(IOException ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Fyi it’s __scrape__ and __scraping__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap or scrapping. ‘To scrap’ means to throw away.

Comment: I suggest that you add the following line of code in the `catch(IOException ex)` block: `ex.printStackTrace();` As your code is now, you don't know if an exception occurred. Since you say that _it doesn't print out everything_, that probably means you are getting an exception.

Comment: I put the "ex.printStackTrace()" in the code like the  question that I update and run .it also blank and not exception show.